# How can I selectively increase latency? E.g. throttle games

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, router, bandwidth

Basically, I want networked games to run poorly on a network, but I want everything else to run smoothly.

I would also appreciate advice on blocking games in general.

As far as I can tell, there's a few ways to completely prevent an internet game from running:

- Blocking entirely via DNS configuration (e.g. hosts file), or router DNS configuration
- Blocking entirely via a separate DNS server
- Blocking the application, by uninstalling or some kind of access control
- Blocking the application by automatically killing the process every once in a while
- Blocking the application by corrupting files periodically

However, I would like a more subtle way to block a program. Something that either:

- Increases latency (would this be doable through some kind of QoS like what DD-WRT offers?)
- Increases latency by using a special routing configuration for specific target IPs
- Throttle other systems resources, such as memory, IO, or CPU
- Screw around with keyboard configurations when a game is launched

I would like this to work on MacOSX and Windows, but Linux would be great too.

FYI I don't have a kid, but I was brainstorming with some friends and parents.

Comment: Quick & very Dirty: Tomato QoS on home router which restricts all UDP traffic to very low bandwith (exceptions for skype and DNS lookups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080119112509736

> Advanced OS X users know that Darwin comes with `ipfw`, which can be
>   used to set up a custom firewall. This same service however can be
>   used to also limit bandwidth on specific ports.
>
> Example: `sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 15KByte/s` creates a pipe that only
>   allows up to 15KB/s to go through.
>
> Then: `sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 src-port 80` will attach that pipe to the
>   outgoing traffic on port 80, effectively limiting the outgoing traffic
>   of the web server. `sudo ipfw delete 1` will remove the pipe from the
>   port.

Comment: Useful to know. thanks! If you knew of a way to do something similar on windows (or a free program to do that), it'd pretty much wrap it up.

Comment: Per David's comment ipfw32 is a port of ipfw to Windows, so you shoudl be about to get it to work there.

Answer (score 0):

There is software called [wanem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) wich can incease lattency(delay), packet loss and bandwith for specific ip, and port in network.
It comes as live CD running linux, but you can run it as virtual machine from some other computer.
All you have to do is proper routing and setting IP-s on network if you have such skills and running this 24/7

Comment: Interesting. I'd prefer if it didn't require a separate machine running 24/7, although it would be okay if it could run embedded on an existing home router. It looks like it also runs in a VM, but that might be pretty conspicuous under certain circumstances.

Comment: YOu probbaly could, I was using this to test how my server performs on loss of data and packets drops and did not went into used tools. 

You might try then netem  http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem . It is by default in kernel 2.6

Answer (score 0):

The IPFIREWALL ( IPFW ) is a FreeBSD sponsored firewall software application authored and maintained by FreeBSD volunteer staff members. Now works on Windows XP/Vista/7!

Please extract to D:\binary\ or change the syntax in wall.cmd

[ipfw32](http://code.google.com/p/ipfw32/)